# How to manage save state in laravel yajra Datatable

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using Yajra datatable for laravel from this [link](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/6.0).
My requirement to save state of datatable.

In this datatable "Html Builder Event Callbacks" are present in this [link](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/6.0/html-builder-callbacks).

But example for how to use "stateSaveCallback" not present. Is any one know how to use this callback for save table state?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried yet before. But, when I look around their documentation, here some possibility. I just reference from https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback and https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

```
$builder->parameters([
    'stateSave'=>true,
    'stateSaveCallback' => 'function(settings,data){ //do your code}',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below example code with api 'backapi/save_state' to store state call back

```
$('#my-datatable').DataTable({
    "stateSave": true,
    "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
        //Custom AJAX to store state
        $.ajax({
            "url": "/api/save_state",
            "data": data,
            "dataType": "json",
            "success": function (response) {}
        });
    },
});
```